# Opposite to/of, across from

Tags: phrases

I went to a place with my friend yesterday, and we got some problems when we was trying to grab a uber.

I couldn't find a suitable term to tell the driver where we were that time.

There were no significant building except for a McDonald's across from the street .

Which way is correct or more proper or more common
1.We are in the opposite to McDonald's 
2.We are in the opposite of McDonald's 
3.We are across the street from McDonald's

Or I should add some noun in the sentence, like

4.We are at the curb, which is opposite to McDonald's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English you would never say 'we are ***in*** the opposite' in this context, it is always just 'we are opposite'.

In this case you could say 'we are opposite McDonald's'.

'We are across the street from McDonald's' sounds fine to me.

Comment: "We are in the opposite of McDonalds" would probably be a cryptic reference: "We are in [Le Gavroche](http://www.le-gavroche.co.uk/)"